ZFS on linux - corrupted directory with missing files, scrub shows no errors?
My file server crashed a couple of days ago, a few hours after some critical files were written.  Now, when I access the directory that contained those files, ls reports errors and the files show up as zero length:
user@athena:/storage/work/freelancing$ ll
ls: project: Input/output error
total 44K
-rw-rw-rw-  1 user work 0 Jul 23 10:13 backup_20240723.tgz
drwxrwsrwx  4 user work 5 Jul 24 07:58 project
drwxrwsr-x+ 5 user work 6 Jul 17 12:03 other

user@athena:/storage/work/freelancing$ cd project/

user@athena:/storage/work/freelancing/project$ ll
ls: scratch-notes: Input/output error
ls: timesheets: Input/output error
total 23K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user work 0 Jul 23 10:22 usernamepassword.txt
drwxrwsrwx 4 user work 4 Jul 24 07:58 scratch-notes
drwxrwsrwx 2 user work 4 Jul 24 07:58 timesheets

However a zfs scrub of the pool identified no issues:
  pool: storage
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 04:23:16 with 0 errors on Thu Jul 25 18:42:45 2024
config:

        NAME                                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        storage                                  ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                               ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD800XXXXX-01VAEB0_VYXXXXXM  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD800XXXXX-01VAEB0_VYXXXXXM  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD800XXXXX-01VAEB0_VYXXXXXM  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

smartctl reports no new errors on the disks (I had an issue with a cable fault a few months ago, and the error notices relating to that still show on the disk that happened to, but nothing else interesting appears there).
I'm using ZFS-on-Linux version 2.1.5 on Ubuntu 22.04.
Using zfs send and zfs recv onto a new pool the missing data isn't copied, but I no longer get error messages from ls, but I'm concerned that any corruption could be affecting other datasets, some of which are too large for me to be able to do this with.
Any ideas what might have caused this problem.
Any ideas how this could have happened, what I can do to prevent it happening in future, and if there is any possibility of (a) recovering my missing data and (b) restoring the pool to a working state without needing to buy new disks to copy the data onto?
Updated: smartctl output is as follows
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.0-117-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Gold
Device Model:     WDC WD8004XXXX-XXXXXX
Serial Number:    XXXXXX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 0cXXXXX
Firmware Version: 01.01H01
User Capacity:    8,001,563,222,016 bytes [8.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jul 26 12:49:02 2024 BST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (   87) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 890) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   132   132   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       96
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   194   194   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       373 (Average 463)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   128   128   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       18
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2351
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       3506
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       3506
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   146   146   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 19/63)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       13

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 13 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 13 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1467 hours (61 days + 3 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 20 00 d8 da 06 40 08      00:01:06.481  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 58 18 18 dc 06 40 08      00:01:06.471  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 18 10 68 db 06 40 08      00:01:06.460  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 28 f8 28 b2 03 40 08      00:01:06.445  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 28 78 48 93 57 40 08      00:01:06.441  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 12 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1467 hours (61 days + 3 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 30 40 f8 e7 30 40 08      00:01:04.608  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 48 00 c3 f0 40 08      00:01:04.602  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 38 d0 74 cd 40 08      00:01:04.596  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 30 28 27 c6 40 08      00:01:04.593  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 30 28 68 60 a0 40 08      00:01:04.590  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 11 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1467 hours (61 days + 3 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 10 a0 00 c3 f0 40 08      00:01:03.790  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 28 e8 c8 c2 f0 40 08      00:01:03.781  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 98 a8 82 55 40 08      00:01:03.732  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 10 e0 98 82 55 40 08      00:01:03.732  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 08 90 58 29 00 40 08      00:01:03.732  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 10 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1467 hours (61 days + 3 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 28 78 b8 f7 5f 40 08      00:01:01.930  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 30 80 b0 f8 5f 40 08      00:01:01.928  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 40 70 b8 f6 5f 40 08      00:01:01.925  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 60 68 90 f3 5f 40 08      00:01:01.924  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 30 60 f8 f1 5f 40 08      00:01:01.922  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 9 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 943 hours (39 days + 7 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 30 68 17 cd 40 08      00:01:05.771  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 28 88 75 ca 40 08      00:01:05.758  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 20 f0 5d c9 40 08      00:01:05.756  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 c0 e0 54 c9 40 08      00:01:05.755  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 b8 58 52 c9 40 08      00:01:05.744  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

Note there is a substantial difference between the power-on time reported and the time of the errors reported.
Also, I previously forgot to mention that there are no messages in the kernel log or other logs relating to this.

@JoepvanSteen Other drives are very similar except without the errors logged.
